# c# change variable memory address

Tags: c#, memory

I have a specific address (let's call it ADR) in my memory with a specific value (let's assume 4 bytes int)

I want to crate an int variable in c# and change the address to that variable to ADR so when I do for example; print myVar it prints the value stored in ADR.

I know I can make an IntPtr(ADR) and then use Marshal Methods to get the value but I want a way to do this without calling a method everytime I have to read the value.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think the address of local variables is always somewhere on the stack, and the address of a field in an object is some offset from the address of the object.  So I don't know of a type of "variable" for which you would be able to choose the address.

Comment: i don't get the reason this is downvoted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you know you can use pointers in C#?

```
int someVariable = 0;

unsafe
{
    int* addr = &someVariable;
    *addr = 42;
}

Console.WriteLine(someVariable); // Will print 42
```

If you already have an address you can just write:

```
int* addr = (int*)0xDEADBEEF;
```

Or, from an `IntPtr`:

```
var intPtr = new IntPtr(0xDEADBEEF);
int* addr = (int*)intPtr.ToPointer();
```

Comment: Might also be worth noting that he'll have to tick `Allow unsafe code` for his project.

Answer (score 0):

One directly approach is invoking ASM code in your C# code, as you can see in [Invoking Assembly Code in C#](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/invoking-assembly-code-c/). Another appropriate option is to use pointers.